# `length` method to be explained

Tags: ruby

Example 1 is an array loop:

**Example 1**

```
counter = []
while counter.length < 3
  puts("Tell me a cool thing!")
  counter2 = gets.chomp
  counter.push(counter2)
end
puts("Here's some cool things in backward order:")
counter3 = counter.length - 1
while counter3 >= 0
  puts(counter[counter3])
  counter3 = counter3 - 1
end
```

The second example is a loop:

**Example 2**

```
counter = 1
while counter.length < 11
  puts counter
  counter += 1
end
```

With `length` applied to example 2, I receive an error. Why? What is the purpose of `length` besides counting the total length of integer?

Comment: Just something to add for example 2.. obviously the code will work find without .length while example 1 will not. don't get it..

Comment: In example 2, counter is a number not the array. And number doesn't have `length` method. That's why it receive an error.

Comment: And the length method's purpose is to count the length / size of the array. That's it. http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.2/Array.html#method-i-length

Comment: Don't forget to select an answer if you find any of them helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To explain in the simplest way possible:

If it's an array, it can technically "measure" the contents with `.length`.
For example, if I have 3 eggs in my basket, and I used `.length` on it, I would get the answer 3, right?

Now if we had only one egg and I *drew* a 3 on it, and I told you to count the amount of eggs, it essentially would always evaluate to one, which isn't really what you're trying to accomplish, so Ruby throws an exception because it doesn't allow this behavior. (It does not allow `.length` to be called on a `Fixnum`)

So in the **first example**, you can think of it this way:

```
 #- Basket                  => your array (counter[])
 #- Egg                     => an element in the array
 #- A Painted number on egg => the *value* of the element in the array

# I have an empty basket
basket = []

# While my basket has less than 3 eggs, keep letting the user add more eggs
while basket.length < 3

  puts("Tell me a cool thing!")

  # Get an egg from the user
  egg = gets.chomp             #=> gets.chomp is the number the user paints on the egg

  # Put that egg in the basket
  basket.push(egg)
end

# So how many eggs are in the basket?
puts basket.length   #=> 3
```

I am going to skip the rest for the sake of simplicity and go straight to your second example:

**Second example**
Same scenario. Baskets, eggs, and paint.

```
# Hey! What happened to the basket? Arrays are baskets! This is just some thing! I guess you want to PAINT a 1 on the basket?
basket = 1

# While my only basket that has a 1 painted on it is less than 11 baskets
while basket.length < 11

   # Show me the number that painted on my only basket
   puts basket

   # Now paint a 2 on my only basket
   basket += 1
end
```

Notice the part where I said *my only* basket? You will always have only 1 basket in this scenario. All we are doing is painting a different number on it on every loop.

**TL;DR**

`Fixnum`s do not have a `.length` method. If it did, almost every loop would be an infinite loop because 1 < 11 will never evaluate to false. This is because there is only *one* Fixnum, the value it represents is essentially irrelevant, and is basicaly a marking painted on the outside of a box.

**If you paint 5 on a box, it does not mean you have 5 boxes.**

Arrays have a `.length` method because you can count the number of things inside them, the same way you can count the number of eggs in a basket.

Hope I helped!

Answer (score 0):

**Example 1** uses length to give you the length of the array `counter`.

**Example 2**, executed independently, doesn't make any sense.  A `Fixnum` has no method `length`.

Answer (score 0):

**Re Example 1**

Cosider this example array:

```
array_one = [1, 3, 4, 8]
```

How many elements does it have? 4. So if I call the `.length` method on it:

```
array_one.length #=> 4
```

'4' is returned so `.length` simply returns the number of elements in an array. And if you think about it, it's kind of like its length using elements as units.

Following on from that, *counter* is in fact an empty **array**:

```
counter = []
```

How many elements? zero, therefore

```
counter.length #=> 0.
```

'0' is returned.

---

**Re Example 2**

In this case `counter = 1` (and has nothing to do with the counter in example 1). So you've assigned the the **number** 1 to the variable **counter**. This is definitely not an array. In short you cannot apply the `.length` method on numbers. So for example trying to apply .`length` in the following examples:

```
2.length #=> NoMethodError...
```

or

```
444.length #=> NoMethodError...
```

Here, you're trying to apply the `.length` method on numbers, which by default makes no sense to Ruby and returns NoMethodError. So in your example:

```
counter.length #=> NoMethodError
```

gives an error because you're trying to call `.length` method on a number, which you can't do.

In Ruby whole numbers belong to the *FixNum class* which by default has no `.length` method (hence the NoMethodError). If I were you, I'd try to get a greater understanding of classes and methods if you can. It will be really useful for you.

Answer (score -1):

Because, by default, `length` is not defined on `Fixnum`.